# How do I set the size of an image from a map in visualforce

Tags: visualforce, map, html, images, size

I have an image being showed in a visualforce page. How do I set the height and width in this case? I tried width="200px" but I cant use this attribute.

See:

```
<cxsrec:hasMapEntry map="{!candidateFieldMap}" key="Image_Url__c">
            <cxsrec:getMapValue map="{!candidateFieldMap}" key="Image_Url__c"  asImage="true" />
        </cxsrec:hasMapEntry>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be using a custom visualforce component. You will have to look at how the component is implemented, and see if there's a way to increase the height and width of the image.